# how can i use ajv-i18n in fastify ？

Tags: ajv, fastify

**Background**

- fastify
- json schema
- ajv

**Problem**

when i add the setErrorHandler to my project/index.js,it doesnt work.

```js
require('module-alias/register')
const Fastify = require('fastify')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
const sequelize = require('./orm')
const swagger = require('./config').swagger
const localize = require('ajv-i18n')
const app = Fastify({
  logger: {
    prettyPrint: true
  },
  ajv: {
    customOptions: {allErrors: true, jsonPointers: true },
    plugins: [
      require('ajv-errors')
    ]
  }
})
app.register(require('fastify-sensible'))
app.register(require('fastify-swagger'), swagger)
app.register(require('./plugin/systemlogs'))
app.register(require('./plugin/authenticate')).then(()=>{
    const routes = require('./routes')
    routes(app).forEach((route, index) => {
      app.route(route)
    })
})
app.setErrorHandler((error,request,reply)=>{
  if (error.validation) {
    localize.ru(error.validation)
    reply.status(400).send(error.validation)
    return
  }
  reply.send(error)
})

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync({})
    app.log.info('database sync correctly')
    await app.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0')
    app.swagger()
  } catch (err) {
    app.log.error(err)
    process.exit(1)
  }
}
start()
```

**Question**

i want to turn the error to chinese with ajv i18n ，what should i do? i do in this way but it doesnt work
how can i use ajv-i18n in fastify ？
where should i add the setErrorHandler?

Comment: Could you add your error schemas if any? They are hidden by `app.route(route)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are another way to deal with this issue.

thanks:

- L2jLiga https://github.com/L2jLiga
- Manuel Spigolon
  url:
- https://github.com/fastify/help/issues/317

this is another way:

```
const fastify = require('fastify')
const localize = require('ajv-i18n')

const app = fastify({
  ajv: {
    customOptions: { allErrors: true, jsonPointers: true },
    plugins: [
      require('ajv-errors')
    ]
  },
  schemaErrorFormatter: (errors, dataVar) => {
    localize.ru(errors);
    const myErrorMessage = errors.map(error => error.message.trim()).join(', ');
    return new Error(myErrorMessage)
  }
})

app.get('/', {
  schema: {
    querystring: {
      type: "object",
      properties: { a: { type: "string", nullable: false } },
      required: ["a"],
    },
  },
}, async function (req, res) {})

app.listen(3000)
```

and example of response:

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "должно иметь обязательное поле a"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here a working snippet to play with; I think your issue is on the routes' schemas.

```js
const Fastify = require('fastify')
const localize = require('ajv-i18n')

const app = Fastify({
  logger: true,
  ajv: {
    customOptions: { allErrors: true, jsonPointers: true }
  }
})

app.post('/', {
  schema: {
    body: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        foo: { type: 'integer' }
      }
    }
  }
}, () => {})

app.setErrorHandler((error, request, reply) => {
  if (error.validation) {
    localize.ru(error.validation)
    reply.status(400).send(error.validation)
    return
  }
  request.log.error({ err: error })
  reply.send(error)
})

app.inject({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/',
  payload: {
    foo: 'string'
  }
}, (_, res) => {
  console.log(res.json())
})
```

That will print out:

```
[
  {
    keyword: 'type',
    dataPath: '/foo',
    schemaPath: '#/properties/foo/type',
    params: { type: 'integer' },
    message: 'должно быть integer'
  }
]
```

Comment: Would you mind to accept the answer if it helped you?